# Firebase Security Rules Storage from specific web url

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to set the security rules of the storage to be that only data that send from my web (specific web url) can be stored. Otherwise no one can write and read.

this is my code:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

but this allows any one to store data. How can I restrict this to my url?

Comment: And what appears to be the issue? Does your code not work? I don't see an actual question here.

Comment: Everyone car store in my storage,I want to set the security rules of the storage to be that only data that send from my web (specific web url) can be stored.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Frank's reply. You can use Firebase authentication with [anonymous user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), so you can create one transparently when a user access your web site and secure the storage with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict what domains people can write from in security rules (as that can be quite easily spoofed).

To ensure all access to your files is authorized, implement Firebase Authentication, and then write rules that reflect what your (signed in) users are allowed to do. See the [Firebase Storage documentation on user-based security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) for more on this.

Comment: This certainly isn't foolproof, but you could use Firebase auth's anonymous sign-in (see "Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously Using JavaScript" in the Docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), and then 

     ```allow read, write: if  request.auth != null```