# Restrict Firebase Storage URL to specific domain

Tags: firebase, storage

Is there any possibility to restrict the firebase storage URLs to access from a specific domain.

I have tried downloadURL() and signedURL() but both are publicly accessible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Security Rules Storage from specific web url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869566/firebase-security-rules-storage-from-specific-web-url)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Nope tried this also.